# how can i show user object data by passing user authentication_token in rails 5 restful json api?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

in v1/controller

class V1::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

```
def index

 if user = User.authentication_keys.present?

    user = User.all

    render json: {status: 'load', message:'load', user: 'user'},status: :ok

    else

    render json: {status: 'error', message:'error', user: 'user'},status: :ok

    end
  end
```

in routes

```
namespace :v1 do
resources :profiles
end
```

i am checking data in postman by passing authentication_token but it not show user object [postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZd6q.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZd6q.png)

my user data in rails console

User id: 1, email: "adarsh1454@codekyt.com", created_at: "2018-11-14 07:35:59", updated_at: "2018-11-14 07:35:59", authentication_token: "tYHzjLm-6xxCeM4RXyEe"

Comment: i am getting close but still i dnt get ans pls need help ==      users = request.headers["authentication_token"].present?
     
     User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers["authentication_token"]) 
      
     render json: users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `'user'` as a string to your json. So it will just send that string.
You could try doing something like:

```
render json: {status: 'load', message:'load', user: user.to_json},status: :ok
```

Or even:

```
render json: user
```

That will get rid of the status and message json attributes, but you could argue the status should be shown by the HTTP response code and you shouldn't need the message if you are passing the user as the response.

*edit*

OK, from your comment I think you probably need something along the lines of:

```
def index
  if request.headers["authentication_token"].present?
    user = User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers["authentication_token"])     
    render json: user
  else
    render json: { .... whatever you want to render if not authorised }
  end
end
```

Comment: users = request.headers["authentication_token"].present?
     
     User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers["authentication_token"]) 
      
     render json: users   i am getting close but still i dnt get  ans pls need help

Answer (score 0):

In successful case, you respond with the following json:

`{status: 'load', message:'load'}`

so everything is working as you described in controller. If you want to return user object, then change it to something like:

`render json: { status: 'load', message:'load', user: 'user' }, status: :ok`

Comment: it show in postman like this  = {
    "status": "load",
    "message": "load",
    "user": "user"
}    it not show user object

Comment: i am getting close but still i dnt get ans pls need help //                                         users = request.headers["authentication_token"].present?
     
     User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers["authentication_token"]) 
      
     render json: users